# Orbot is Unreasonably Slow

Tags: orbot, iptables

I decided to start using orbot due to the tracking apparently being done by AT&T.

I am unable however to get any sort of borderline acceptable internet speeds....When I try go to a webpage it is more likely to timeout than anything else. My down speeds seem to always stay < 5 Kbps....

A post on xda (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1824006[1] ) advised trying to reconnect repeatedly to find a good fast route. I tried reconnecting and connecting a few times and then it seems I stumbled on a reliable circuit that actually let me load webpages.

But, I immediately disconnected and tried again, and bam, back to slow speeds....

Is there any way to reliably get a reasonable speed in orbot that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you see the slow speed when using the mobile network and/or on your home Wifi/WLAN?

Comment: Both unfortunately...

Comment: I get this problem too. Has solved?

Comment: This is not an answer. Please ask another question, or upvote this question. At any rate, I never have this problem with Orbot, so for me, the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, @SuperSluether . It would be help for anyone have the problem like me, if you share how to configure your phone and Orbot setting. So Orbot dont make slow user network connection.

Comment: All I did was install the app and connect, without changing any settings. I use the Orfox browser.